# {"msg":"invalid_request"} getting Error when i am Using nodemailer in Nodejs to send mail from Gmail

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean

When I am trying to send mail from Gmail. I am getting "{"msg":"invalid_request"}" error in response.

Below is the code.

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
  smtpTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
        user: 'pathareshekhar29@gmail.com',
        pass: 'XYZ'
      })
    }
  })
);

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'pathareshekhar29@gmail.com',
  to: user.empEmail,
  subject: 'User Account Approval',
  text: 'Demo Mail'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
  console.log('ygcasyhgbavsdbahvbdb   '+ err);
  if (err) { 
    return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); 
  } else {
    res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.empEmail + '.');
  }           
});
```

Could anyone please help me to fix this error.

Comment: Hi Shekhar, according to the log this error is ocurring at the back end server, let's have a look at your backend server log, Error 500 means internal server error, you will need more information from you backend server to find out the root cause of the issue.

Comment: thank you very much Daniel...

Comment: var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            auth: {
              xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
              user: 'pathareshekhar29@gmail.com',
              pass: 'XYZ'
              })
            }
          }));

Comment: var mailOptions = {
            from: 'pathareshekhar29@gmail.com',
            to: user.empEmail,
            subject: 'User Account Approval',
            text: 'Demo Mail'
          };

Comment: transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
            console.log('ygcasyhgbavsdbahvbdb   '+ err);
            if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
            else{
               res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.empEmail + '.');
            }           
          });

Comment: please, post this additional information to your question description, edit your question and add more information about your server logs

Comment: okay sure Daniel..thanks :)

Comment: @shekharpathare, I've edited your post to provide code indentation. You can do this by indenting each line at least 4 characters, or using backticks ``